# Storing random numbers in an array of bytes

Tags: assembly, x86-16, masm

I want to store random numbers from 1 to 5 in an array of 100 bytes. My *random* procedure is working well but it did not show any output when I tried to print my array. This program did not show any output. I have checked my random number procedure and it works fine, but I think there is some issue with storing and printing.
Here is my code:

```
    .model small
    .stack 100h
    .data
    arrayelement db 100 dup('$'); To store array
    randomnumber db 0; to store random number
    r1 db ?
    .code
    main proc
        mov ax,@data
        mov ds,ax
  
        mov cx,100
        mov si,offset arrayelement
        forr:
    
            call random
            mov al,randomnumber
            mov [si],al
            inc si
            
        loop forr
    
        mov dl,10
        mov ah,02h
        int 21H
        mov dl,13
        mov ah,02h
        int 21H
    
        mov si,offset arrayelement
        mov cx,100
        for1:
        mov dl,[si]
        ;add dl,48
        mov ah,02
        int 21h
        inc si
        loop for1
        
        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h
    main endp
;Random procedure to print randomnumber between 1 to 5
    random proc
        mov ax,0
        mov bx,0
        mov cx,0
        mov dx,0
;Loop to slow down time so it print different random number on each call
      mov cx,500
      l11:
        push cx
        mov cx,500
      l222:
        Loop l222
        pop cx
        Loop l11
      MOV AH, 00h  ; interrupts to get system time        
       INT 1AH      ; CX:DX now hold number of clock ticks since midnight      
    
       mov  ax, dx
       xor  dx, dx
       mov  cx, 5 ;Ending  
     
       div  cx       ; here dx contains the remainder of the division - from 1-5
    
       add  dl, 1  ; start--to ascii from '1' to '5'
       mov randomnumber,dl
      
      ret
      random endp
    end main
```

Comment: Use a debugger to single-step your code: when `random` returns, CX is always 5, so `loop` is always taken.  Use a register for you loop counter which your function doesn't destroy. 
 Also, you could use any PRNG algorithm that you seed once, instead of using a delay loop(!) to give the clock time to tick.  And you could just return the random number in AL like a normal function, or even in DL where it already is.  You generally don't need to use global variables.

Comment: Duplicate of [TASM infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37810356) - same problem of a function call clobbering the loop counter, but nobody's upvoted my answer there.  I'm sure there must be other duplicates, but having a hard time finding them.

Answer (score -1):

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
arrayelement db 100 dup('$'); To store name
randomnumber db 0; to store random number
r1 db ?
.code
main proc
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    
    mov cx,100
    mov si,offset arrayelement
    forr:

        call random
        mov al,randomnumber
        mov [si],al
        inc si
        
    loop forr

    mov dl,10
    mov ah,02h
    int 21H
    mov dl,13
    mov ah,02h
    int 21H

    mov si,offset arrayelement
    mov cx,100
    for1:
    mov dl,[si]
    add dl,48
    mov ah,02
    int 21h
    inc si
    loop for1
    
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
main endp
random proc
    push cx
    push ax
    push dx
  mov cx,500
  l11:
    push cx
    mov cx,500
  l222:
    Loop l222
    pop cx
    Loop l11
  MOV AH, 00h  ; interrupts to get system time        
   INT 1AH      ; CX:DX now hold number of clock ticks since midnight      

   mov  ax, dx
   xor  dx, dx
   mov  cx, 5 ;Ending  
 
   div  cx       ; here dx contains the remainder of the division - from 1-5

   add  dl, 1  ; start--to ascii from '1' to '5'
   mov randomnumber,dl
  pop cx
    pop ax
    pop dx
  ret

  random endp
end main
```

Comment: I see that you have tried to correct your program following the comment provided by @PeterCordes. It's OK to preserve the registers involved on the stack **but you must restore those registers in reverse order** because that is how the stack works. It's Last In, First Out. So `push cx` `push ax` `push dx` must ultimately lead to `pop dx` `pop ax` `pop cx` `ret`